# How to manage multiple C++ files when using Android NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I  have  a native part in my android application. I will use the android NDK framework for this purpose. But the most of tutorials (including android ndk samples and opencv samples) use only one C++ source file.

1) How can I manage multiple source files?

2) Should I have an Android.mk file for each file source?

Any tutorial about this problem is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `android-ndk-r9\samples\san-angeles\` example has multiple source files. This should be a good enough example